# How to write realtime datastream flink data in parquet file format in HDFS

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

1.How to write data in parquet format to HDFS through flink datastream processing.

2.Also, while providing path for state using rocksdb, the folder is getting created in provided HDFS path but nothing is written, size is zero. Do I need to give any other configurations along with the "env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("HDFS://path",true));
true- for incremental write.

3. For checkpoint, have given the HDFS path directory, only shared and taskowned folders are created and no checkpoint folder.

Can someone help with these issues with code or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you enabled checkpointing? By default, checkpointing is turned off.

Comment: Now I am able to checkpoint and write the data in HDFS. Using rocksdb I am not able to write data to HDFS. I have enabled state.backend: rocksdb